# Automatically close application when i call intent.createChooser to send mail?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

In my android application having one button to send mail, When I click that send button using `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail..."));` this line Gmail will open and then I click send mail. Mail will sent successfully at the same time my application get closed why ? I need to stay in that same page ?

```
try 
{
        String extpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/NewFolder/DBName";
        File pathp=new File(extpath);
        Log.d("New Path", pathp.toString());

        long fileSize = pathp.length();
        if(fileSize > 0)
        {

            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            String address = "mailid@yourmail.com";
            String subject = "Database";
            String emailtext = "Please check the attached database and save it";

            emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { address });

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + pathp));

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail..."));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Error", "Attachment didn't attach ");
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        Log.d("Error on sending mail", t.toString());
    }
```

When i run this code mail sent and then application will get close. I don't want to close application. Help me thanks in advance.

Comment: post some relevant code

Comment: @kgandroid I updated my question kindly read it

Comment: @Sri You got any errors??

Comment: your code seems to be ok.Can you post your logcat??

Comment: I think you called `finish()` to `Activity` or clear `Activity back stack` that's why you cant return back to your app and your app is get closed....

Comment: yeah... i used this code in **manifest** `noHistory=true` that's why my app get closed. Thank you friends for your valuable comments and time. Now its solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button button;
Session session;
ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SendMailBySite bySite=new SendMailBySite();
    bySite.execute();

}


class SendMailBySite extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{  



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Sending mail.....");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          final String user="XXXXXXXX@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
          final String password="XXXXXXX";//change accordingly  

          String to="toXXXXXXXX@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

           //Get the session object  
          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
             props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
             props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
             props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
             props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

           Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
              }  
            });  

           //Compose the message  
            try {  
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
             message.setSubject("Mobiappsdevelper");  
             message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");  

            //send the message  
             Transport.send(message);  



             } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 


        return null;


    }  
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message sent successfully...", 3000).show();
    }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```